# How to specify only those JUnit files that end with a specific string in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: junit, intellij-idea

I just got in to an old project. In this project there are specific naming conventions for the *unit tests*: all such files must end with JUnit (i.e. `*JUnit.java`).

How can I configure the JUnit plugin in the IntelliJ IDEA 12 to test only these files?

Comment: Related: [In IntelliJ IDEA, can I run only tests matching a regex pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144469/in-intellij-idea-can-i-run-only-tests-matching-a-regex-pattern/43182331).

Answer (score 1):

I think, the *Pattern* could help you. Have a look at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-junit.html

Comment: Thanks, that link is helpful. The thing I didn't understand is that the pattern is for fully qualified java names.

Comment: The pattern is for the class name without extension and package.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Without package? Actually due to the fact that the package in Java is part of the [_fully qualified name_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) it **must be included** when constructing a regex in the "Pattern" field. At least this is the case in the latest IntelliJ IDEA version as of now (2020.1.1). It took me some time to figure this out when I was writing a regex for the TestNG classes whose names begin with "B2B". Writing `^B2B.*` didn't work, I was confused etc, until it got to me that I need to use the "fully qualified name". Now it works )