# In IntelliJ IDEA, can I run only tests matching a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, pattern-matching

is it possible to create a Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ that picks up only those files that match a regular expression?

I want to run all my unit tests. I don't want to run integration tests written by my colleagues. Integration tests contain the text "IT", so I thought the following regex would do:

```
^((?!IT).)*$
```

But it didn't.

**EDIT**

As a trivial example, I tried the following regex:

`^.*IT.*$`

(which does exactly the opposite of what I want to achieve), but still I fail. It still picks up every single Test and runs it.

Example tests that get picked up:

```
com.my_company.session.SessionTest.java
com.my_company.test.server.api.ITAuthentication.java
```

[image]

This is what the Test results panel looks like

[image]

Comment: The `^((?!IT).)*$ ` matches a line that does not contain `IT` substring. Is that what you need? If you mean to match the whole text not containing `IT`, you need to use `(?s)` at the beginning. If you need to match any text having `IT`, you need `(?s).*IT`. If you need to match the entire string, use `(?s).*IT.*`

Comment: yep, I want to match any test file that doesn't contain the text "IT".

Comment: Then please try `(?s)^(?!.*IT)` or `(?s)^(?!.*IT).*`. Are you using them in [this window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104807/3832970)?

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104807/104891). Does it help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your comment. Unfortunately it didn't work. Could it be something related to IntelliJ configuration?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I hadn't seen your answer before. It does make perfect sense. However I cannot make it work...

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I added a screenshot of my configuration and an example of two test classes that get picked up. I also tried my regex on https://regex101.com/ to make sure that I'm not wasting your time. What other information can I provide?

Comment: The following regex works for me: `^(?!.*IT.*).*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

doesn't work with JUnit 5

**Long answer**

CrazyCoder kindly responded to my [post on Jetbrain's forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000142510-JUnit-configuration-with-Pattern-not-matching). He provided an answer and also uploaded his working project. That was helpful because I verified that pattern matching worked fine on his project.

Then another Jetbrain engineer responded to my How-To request. He pointed out [IDEA-164088, JUnit 5 doesn't support pattern configurations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164088)

That's a known issue and will be fixed on versions 2017.2.X coming up on April 2017.

**Solution**

A workaround until then, is to use JUnit5 tags

```
@Tag("junit")
public class MyTest
```

and then run the following configuration that only picks up test classes annotated with that particular tag.

[image]

P.S. Actually, using Tags seems an even more elegant solution for the given task as long as the number of test classes is limited.

Comment: This feature is now available for JUnit 5 tests.

Answer (score 13):

I've already [provided the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104807/104891) which describes how to exclude `*IT.java` tests, but as your question is different and you want to exclude `*IT*.java` tests (any test that has `IT` in its name), the pattern would be different:

```
^(?!.*IT.*).*$
```

[image: Exclude IT]

Note that it will not work with JUnit 5 in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1, there is a known bug that is fixed for 2017.2 version:

- [IDEA-164088](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164088) JUnit 5 doesn't support pattern configurations

Comment: still nothing. Is it possible that I am missing something else? E.g. some default setting/intellij configuration

Comment: I've replied you in [the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000142510-JUnit-configuration-with-Pattern-not-matching?page=1#community_comment_115000185044).

Answer (score 2):

You can run all test case in a class, after that >> select some test case by hold **Ctrl** and **click mouse** >> run, then open config run and copy the pattern to edit more..