# Run specific tests on Intellij using JUnit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I would like to run all test classes whose names end with "UnitTest". I'm using Intellij 2017.2.5 and tried to create a JUnit Run/Debug Configuration and select only classes that have the specific format (*UnitTest).

Unfortunately didn't work, even using the Patter Test Kind.

So my question is: how can I create a JUnit Run configuration on Intellij to run only test's classes which finished with "UnitTest"?

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182331/104891 answer your question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder yeap! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Maven Surefire plugin, it's possible to include/exclude the test sources based on the exact names or a pattern. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) you can find more details.

Technically, a configuration similar to this should do the work:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>%regex[.*UnitTest.*]</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? SO should make it mandatory to leave a comment when people downvote.

Comment: @adiedx_ the question was specific to IntelliJ IDEA IDE and how to do it in the IDE so that the built-in test runner is used showing the tests tree, etc, not just the logs as Maven does (no, I didn't downvote it). Also, it appears that this question already has the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182331/104891.

Comment: Hi Folks, thank you for your comments. I think the answer should solve the OP's issue, at least partially. Even if it is not 100% compliant, in that case I think it don't deserve downvotes. That's my opinion. I let the community decide whether it should be there or not.